# Does Google AdWords revisit the landing page to see if it changed?

Tags: google-ads

If I change the landing page of my ads on Google AdWords to fit better with the exact wording on the ads, will Google notice this change and update the ads' quality score?

Answer (score 1):

Definately, It will revisit every time you make some changes in your ads slot. But, If you keep everything as it is like ad copy, url and keywords same but only makes changes to landing page then it won't as you are not changing the ad copy but once you change it will check for sure.